# PyCharm calls packaging_tool.py list again and again

Tags: python, pycharm

I have several user accounts on my linux PC.

Each is running a virtual env in $HOME.

PyCharm works nice in several of them.

But in one virtualenv it constantly uses a lot of CPU. PyCharm does react very slow, and sometimes not at all concerning searches ("find Usage" or "ctrl-shift-f").

Normal editing works fine.

But double-click on a class name to jump to the definition of the class does not work.

I checked what's wrong with the command line tool `top`.

I see that this gets executed over and over again:

```
python /snap/pycharm-community/117/helpers/packaging_tool.py list
```

The process has a new PID every second.

The virtualenv is on a local SSD disk.

What could be wrong here?

Versions: PyCharm 2018.3.5, Python 2.7, Ubuntu 18.04

I removed ~/.PyCharmCE2018.3/ and started again from scratch. Same issue again.

Here is the output of above script: https://pastebin.com/StPqJns6

Comment: Did you try manually running `python /snap/pycharm-community/117/helpers/packaging_tool.py list` from the faulty *VEnv* and from another one that works? I suspect that the process crashes for some reason (your *VEnv* is corrupted) and it's being restarted, resulting an endless loop. Although I think this is also a *PyCharm* bug, apparently the only way of going around this situation would be to fix / recreate your faulty *VEnv*.

Comment: @CristiFati I see nothing unusual in the output. I added a link to the output in the question.

Comment: So no difference between one env that works and the one that doesn't? Not even in terms of process exit code?

Comment: There is a log file in your `<user>/.pycharm/system/log/idea.log` folder. anything there that could give a clue ? did you compare the virtual env packages list with each users' virtual env (beyond compare or similar); something might stand out ? Here I have several lines that look like `2019-03-14 10:16:28,039 [397170163] INFO - packaging.PyPackageManagerImpl - Running packaging tool: D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\StackOverflowQuestions\python.exe E:\DEV\PyCharm_Community_Edition_2018.3.5\helpers\packaging_tool.py list` (ok, its windows, but you get the point).